# iOS Customize UItableView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am very new to iOS development. I am pretty familiar with Android and Android Studio but I am really struggling with iOS and xcode.

Basically what I want to do is add another title to the header, under the title that is provided to you through creating a UItableview. Is there any way to do this through the storyboard, or would code be a better option? If so, how should I attempt to do this. I have not really been able to find much about this by google searching and the information I have found isn't incredibly applicable.

This is my first question so I can't add a picture. This is what it looks like and I want to add a second title that will display the date and location under EVENT NAME:

### EVENT NAME

### -------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From storyboard you can just drag a UIView into your UITableView, ABOVE any Cells that are in the table, this will become your HeaderView. From there you can drag whatever you want into the view.
[image]

Comment: You're welcome, if this helped, please approve it as the answer to help others find it.

Comment: I upvoted it, however, it will not show up that I upvoted because I don't have 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view in xib and implement tableview delegate method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // return custom xib view 
}
```

here you may need to give height for header as well to show custom view.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // return height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through storyboard and then use tags for any UIButtons, UILabels, etc that you want to add to it.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
   UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HEADER_CELL"];

   // Stuff you want to do to your header
   // Tag can be anything except 0. You set this in the interface builder
   UILabel * myHeaderLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
   UILabel * myHeaderSubLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

   myHeaderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d", section];
   myHeaderLabel.text = @"Subtext";

   return cell; 
}
```